# SVG Rendering Issues

Tags: html, svg, cross-browser

I've run into some SVG rendering bugs in all browsers except Chrome. The SVGs are all embedded in the HTML file, which is supported by all current browsers. However, most browsers get the colors wrong (which are just standard hex colors), while others fail to render some at all (and others just fine). Here's the source file and screenshots: http://awesomegeek.com/bugreport/bugreport.zip See for yourself and let me know if you can replicate it or come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid your html file is invalid. You've got multiple elements with the same id e.g. linearGradient id="a". I know they occur in different svg fragments but you still can't do that, all Ids must be globally unique in the file. I think Firefox is drawing the icons correctly by picking out the first one of these in the file as a whole.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the color issues in Firefox and IE9. However, Safari and the Android browsers are still only partially rendering the SVGs. Any idea why that's happening? Here's the updated code: http://pastebin.com/9J6bKsvv

Comment: Chrome and Safari use the same rendering engine (Webkit) so it likely will work in some newer Safari. Safari updates at a lower frequency than Chrome and I believe the latest Safari requires a fairly recent Mac OS. Same with Android I guess.

Comment: Well that sucks, but it answers my question. I guess I'll have to stick with JPEGs for now. Thanks anyway.